# Multiple sequential outgoing calls in a single session

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have this scenario, where a user will select multiple contacts from CRM. He will click start calling, crm will generate a pin, user will call an incoming twilio number, enter the pin, if the pin is correct, the session will start and the call will be placed to contact in the same call session. Once that call with contact is ended we dont want to disconnect the session but rather when user clicks call next contact, and the call will be placed to next contact in the same session as we dont want user to call twilio number again and again.

Is it possible to achieve something like this in twilio?
If yes, then can you guide me on this, especially the part where we keep a single incoming call session to twilio number and then placing multiple outbound calls sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is possible. You said you want the user to click "next call" and dial the next number. What you'll need to do is, when the user enters the pin number make sure you record the user's Call Sid for the session.

Then, I assume you will have some TwiML setup that uses [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to make the call to the third party. The key here is that once that call is over, Twilio makes a request to the [`action` attribute of the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action). If you return more TwiML to that request then the call will continue. If you wanted, you could return the next number to `<Dial>` and the call to the next person will start immediately. If you want your user to be in charge then I would return some TwiML that loops in a holding fashion (possibly using [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) to repeat a message or just play some music). Then, when the user presses "next call" you make a request to the REST API to [modify the live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) using the Call Sid and redirect it to some new TwiML that `<Dial>`s the next number.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, i will try this method,
and also, can i also achieve my scenario through conference feature of twilio?

Comment: You could keep dialling users into the conference that your user is in, yes. You'd need to [initiate those calls using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) though, rather than with TwiML as I've described here.

Comment: so i created that according to that solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389420/9252017, it worked great, untill i had to detect voice mail, which is not allowed using dial and action method, its only possible through rest api call method, but when i do that i cant catch the call for loop, it exits the moment call is dialed. any idea how i can catch it for loop?